# Could't access the resource file in another xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've a project with `styles` were defined in a `xaml` file under a Themes folder. Hence, I couldn't add `resource` in another xaml file which is under View folder. It shows "`The file 'Controls\MyContentPaneDictionary.xaml`' is not part of the project or it's '`Build Action`' property is not set to Resources.

How could I solve this problem ? The answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What it's `Build Action` property value?

Comment: Previously it was none. I tried with 'Resources' also, however no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the file's **Build Action to Resource** and do a full rebuild(to make sure visual studio notices the change to the resources) or you could even delete the build files and then build the file again.

Comment: I did what you suggested, however no hope, not resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the build action to 'Page' and CustomTool to 'MSBuild:Compile'

Comment: By default it was 'Page' and 'MSBuild:Compile' only.

Comment: Could you post your folder tree structure here?